Underdispersion handled with negative binomial distribution?
To get a more flexible model than Poisson regression, one can choose the negative binomial distribution instead for modeling with $E[y] = \mu$ and $Var(y) = \mu + \frac{1}{ \theta} \mu^2$. As a consequence we would require $\theta < 0$ for underdispersion.
I have in mind that the limiting cases are such that:

Poisson Distribution: $\theta$ → $\infty$
Geometric Distribution: $\theta = 1$

Considering this, is it even possible to handle underdispersion with the negative binomial regression?

No I don't believe that the standard negative binomial distribution could ever be a valid model for under dispersed data, as I believe that $\theta < 0$ produces an invalid variance function.
Consider the variance function for a NB distribution where $\theta < 0$
$$
 V(y) = \mu + \frac{1}{\theta}\mu^2 = \mu - \frac{1}{\alpha}\mu^2, \ \alpha = -\theta > 0
$$
Then, for any fixed $\alpha > 0$ as $\mu \uparrow$ we have that $V(y)\downarrow$, and importantly there will be some point where $V(y) < 0$ as $\mu \uparrow$.
